# Server side paging with JqxGrid and Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, get, jqxgrid

I was trying to implement server side paging with JqxGrid and Codeigniter. I am following the tutorial here, http://www.jqwidgets.com/server-side-paging-with-jquery-grid/. I have a problem with posting pagenum and pagesize to Codeigniter controller. When I tried $this->input->get('') method, its not working.

Here is my Source for jqxgrid,

```
 var source =
     {
         datatype: "json",
         datafields: [
         { name: 'itemname'},
         { name: 'category'},
        ],
         id: 'id',
         url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/cart/reportgriddata/"; ?>',

         root: 'Rows',
            beforeprocessing: function(data)
            {       
                source.totalrecords = data[0].TotalRows;
            }
         };
```

And in my controller, I used following method to get parameters from get-url of dataadapter

```
 $pagenum =$this->input->get('pagenum');
 $pagesize =$this->input->get('pagesize');
```

But here the values getting for both $pagenum and $pagesize is null.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using POST method.

```
var source =
     {
         type:"POST"
         datatype: "json",
         datafields: [
         { name: 'itemname'},
         { name: 'category'},
        ],
         id: 'id',
         url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/cart/reportgriddata/"; ?>',

         root: 'Rows',
            beforeprocessing: function(data)
            {       
                source.totalrecords = data[0].TotalRows;
            }
         };
```

and using,

```
 $pagenum =$this->input->post('pagenum');
 $pagesize =$this->input->post('pagesize');
```